# Metrics Server and Prometheus have overwriting resources

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to install [Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server), but it needs to create a resource that already exists from an installation of Prometheus.  They both want to make `v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io`.

I went to see if the resource was the same, so I could just leave it.  But they are not.  They each have a `service:` section that points to their respective services (`prometheus-adapter` and `metrics-server`).

If I install the Metrics Server version, then I lose the settings for Prometheus.  I am hoping that these are not mutually exclusive tools.  (They do not fill the same function. Prometheus is for monitoring and the Metrics Server is for Horizontal Pod Scaling.)

**How can I install Metrics Server without messing up Prometheus?**

---

In case it is useful, here is the full yaml for the conflicting definitions of v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io:

**Prometheus:**

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: metrics-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v0.10.0
  name: v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
spec:
  group: metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  service:
    name: prometheus-adapter
    namespace: ntnx-system
    port: 443
  version: v1beta1
  versionPriority: 100
```

**Metrics Server:**

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1   
kind: APIService    
metadata:   
  labels:   
    k8s-app: metrics-server 
  name: v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io  
spec:   
  group: metrics.k8s.io 
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100 
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true   
  service:  
    name: metrics-server    
    namespace: kube-system  
  version: v1beta1  
  versionPriority: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

A way around this issue is to just change the name of each APISerice..Or better yet just change the metric servers name for example.

```yml
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: metrics-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v0.10.0
  name: v1beta1.metrics-server.k8s.io
spec:
  group: metrics-server.k8s.io # Change the group to something unique
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  service:
    name: prometheus-adapter
    namespace: ntnx-system
    port: 443
  version: v1beta1
  versionPriority: 100
```

Just keep in mind that the metadata.name must be `spec.version+"."+spec.group.
I hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!  I thought about doing this, but I don’t know if there will be side effects. For example, will Metrics Server go looking for the APIService under the original (expected) name?